# Split string in python

Tags: python

I have an input on the form 'A7-A5'

How can i get that input to a list like: `[['A',7],['A',5]]`

Comment: Is it always one letter and one digit?

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> a = "A7-A5"
>>> b = [[i[0], int(i[1])] for i in a.split("-")]
>>> b
[['A', 7], ['A', 5]]
```

Comment: or, `map(list, a.split('-'))`

Comment: @Andrew: That won't convert the digit to an integer, though.